# Power BI exchange rate

Tags: powerbi, dax

in Power Bi i have two tables .

Table 1

| COUNTRY | Sales |
| --- | --- |
| CHN | 100 |
| JPN | 100 |

Table 2

| COUNTRY | ToUSD Exchange rate |
| --- | --- |
| CHN | 7 |
| JPN | 135 |

i have a measures

TOTALSALES = sum(Table1[Sales])

TOTALSALES_USD = ????

I don't want to calculate the value of the USD for each rows .

I want to sum USD for individual country and sum again .

If I choose one country  , it will convert the USD for 1 country .

if I choose two country , it will totalsales (CHN) (CHN to USD RATE) + totalsales (JPN) (JPN to USD RATE)

how to write the DAX

TOTALSALES_USD

Answer (score 0):

This works if you have a single Rate value for each country and your tables are linked 1-M.

```
=
Sumx(
    'Table2'
    ;SumX(
           Relatedtable('Table1')
           ;[Sales])*[ToUSD Exchange rate]
)
```